# Reducing numbers behind comma in R stacked barchart label

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I computed the following data in order to plot labels to my stacked barchart in R:

```
    Scenario Losses      Model   percent
1 Scenario 1  23221   Upstream 0.6095231
2 Scenario 1  14876 Downstream 0.3904769
3 Scenario 2    722   Upstream 0.3764338
4 Scenario 2   1196 Downstream 0.6235662
5 Scenario 3  28487   Upstream 0.7256355
6 Scenario 3  10771 Downstream 0.2743645
```

When I plot this:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = Scenario, y = percent, fill = Model, label = paste(percent * 100, "%", sep = ""))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", color = "black", alpha=0.8)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00008B", "#800080"))+ 
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2)
```

The resulting graph is:

[image]

The solution to this has been widely discussed online. By adding the following code, the number of commas ought to be reduced:

```
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::percent(percent, accuracy=0.1))
```

I've tried a number of workarounds but everytime I end up with:

```
Error in number(x = x, accuracy = accuracy, scale = scale, prefix = prefix,  : 
  object 'percent' not found
```

I can't really fanthom what I need to chance since I saw precisely this code chunk being run succesfully on another thread.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `round` to your `label` to show for example only two `digits` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test, aes(x = Scenario, y = percent, fill = Model, label = paste(round(percent * 100, 2), "%", sep = ""))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", color = "black", alpha=0.8)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00008B", "#800080"))+ 
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data used:**

```
test = read.table(text = "    Scenario Losses      Model   percent
1 Scenario_1  23221   Upstream 0.6095231
2 Scenario_1  14876 Downstream 0.3904769
3 Scenario_2    722   Upstream 0.3764338
4 Scenario_2   1196 Downstream 0.6235662
5 Scenario_3  28487   Upstream 0.7256355
6 Scenario_3  10771 Downstream 0.2743645", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and also generating the data.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `paste`, use `sprintf` as shown below:

```
 label = sprintf("%.2f%%",percent * 100)
```

ie

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = Scenario, y = percent, fill = Model,
                 label = sprintf("%.2f%%",percent * 100))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", color = "black", alpha=0.8)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00008B", "#800080"))+ 
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

And yet another approach would be to use `scales::percent` for both the text labels and the axis labels like so:

Note: Shameless stolen the data from @Quinten.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(test, aes(x = Scenario, y = percent, fill = Model, label = scales::percent(percent))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", color = "black", alpha = 0.8) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00008B", "#800080")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! May I ask why the initial code did not work? I saw it used somewhere else and I still don't get why R returns "percent not found"

Comment: The issue was that you used `label = scales::percent(percent)` in the scale instead of in geom_text. Inside the scale you can't access the values of the asethetics, that's why you got the error `'percent' not found`. Via the scale we only define how the axis labels are formatted. To this end we have to pass a labeller function to the `labels` argument.